# How can I unzip a gzipped file in the browser?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gzip

So I am having trouble sending PBF files from the server to the client gzipped. Everything else is gzipped except those files and I can't understand why. So I have decided to gzip the files before hand and I want to unzip them in the browser.

Here is where I will receive the gzipped file:

```
var soil = L.mbTiles("data/myLayer/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf.gz", {
    name: "myLayer",
    storage: "myLayer",
    mbtileLayerName: "myLayer",
    maxNativeZoom: 10,
    minNativeZoom: 10,
    minZoom: 6,
    bounds: L.latLngBounds([36.9,-116.2],[35.0,-113.9])
})
```

Now I will modify mbTiles and I want to unzip it before it does anything with that data. How do I do this?

**EDIT**
Here is my server.js:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var compression = require('compression');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
var session = require('client-sessions');
var path = require('path');
var expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(compression({ threshold: 0 }));
app.use(loopback.static(__dirname+'../'));
//app.use("/test/data", expressStaticGzip("../views/test/data"));

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

Comment: @positlabs I posted my server.js file. It does seem counterproductive but I've tried many other solutions for my problem and I can't get it so I want to try this way to at least get the data to render. Every other file has the gzip header except for these files. Which is needed to work for mbTiles.

Comment: @positlabs Also how is this a duplicate? I am trying to decompress in the client not compress files.

Comment: You're right. I retracted the close vote. Are you sure your paths are correct? Try using path.resolve in conjunction with __dirname to ensure you are pointing to the correct directory.

Comment: @positlabs I just checked it and it seems to be correct

Comment: I think I may have been looking in the wrong place. I believe expressStaticGzip is superfluous, since you already have the compression module. With the server-side compression, you aren't trying to load a .gz file directly, right? The compression module on the server gzips on the fly, and the browser decompresses on the fly. You should only need to load the uncompressed file, and the rest will happen automatically.

Comment: @positlabs The compression is working, I can see that it is gzipping my index and other javascript files. But when I try to import the .pbf files I have stored on my server, they do not import compressed. So I was trying to gzip them myself before importing then decompressing myself but that method did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the compression module that those files are compressible. You can define a filter method in the compression options object.

> filter
>
> A function to decide if the response should be considered for
>   compression. This function is called as filter(req, res) and is
>   expected to return true to consider the response for compression, or
>   false to not compress the response.
>
> The default filter function uses the compressible module to determine
>   if res.getHeader('Content-Type') is compressible.